# DoesNotExist at /cafelist/1

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm making website using Python Framework of 'Django'.

I have some problems with Django about post number.

when I visit the website https://tutorialproject-ggurf.run.goorm.io/cafelist/1, I receive this message:

```
DoesNotExist at /cafelist/1
Cafe matching query does not exist.
```

**settings.py contains:**

```
    """
Django settings for tutorialdjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorialdjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorialdjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MEDIA_ROOT')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py contains:**

```
"""tutorialdjango URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from main.views import index, cafelist, cafedetails
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('cafelist/', cafelist),
    path('cafelist/<int:pk>', cafedetails, name='cafedetails'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py contains:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cafe

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')

def cafelist(request):
    cafelist = Cafe.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/cafelist.html', {'cafelist': cafelist})

def cafedetails(request, pk):
    cafeobj = Cafe.objects.get(pk = pk)
    return render(request, 'main/cafedetails.html', {'cafeobj': cafeobj})
```

**models.py contains:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Cafe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    mainphoto = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True)
    content = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**index.html contains:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Django!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Test!</h1>
      {% load static %}
          <img src="{% static 'jeju.jpg' %}">
  </body>
</html>
```

**cafelist.html contains:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>cafelist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>cafelist</h1>
        <table>
            {% for list in cafelist %}
            <tr onclick="{% url 'cafedetails' list.id %}">
                <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ list.content }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**cafedetails.html contains:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>cafelist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>cafelist</h1>
        <p>
            {{ cafeobj.name }}
        </p>
        <p>
           {{ cafeobj.content }} 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: consider using django-rest-framework and react. this will make your life much easier. as to this specific case, without error logs it is difficult to tell, this could be any of: unapplied migrations, url path issue, empty database.... the list goes on.

Comment: The empty database is probably your case. Can you check in your admin panel if there is a record With id =1

Comment: btw, you should really avoid to share your SECRET_KEY in SO !

Comment: @EricMartin haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your `cafedetails` page, you are getting this error message:

> `DoesNotExist at /cafelist/1  Cafe matching query does not exist.`

This means that you haven't created a `Cafe` model with the `pk` of 1.
Try creating a few `Cafe` models from Django Admin or `python manage.py shell` and see if the error persists.